# How do I change specific content between tags in a file using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I have a virtual host apache config file and I want to change all content inside the tag `<VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost>` using a shell script.

I have this in virtualhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.foo.bar

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/src/

    <Directory /var/www/html/src/>
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?m=$1 [QSA]
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mysite.foo.bar

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/src/

        <Directory /var/www/html/src/>
            Require all granted
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?m=$1 [QSA]
            DirectoryIndex index.php
        </Directory>

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/foo/bar/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/foo/bar/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/foo/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And, using a shell script, I want to change it for this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.foo.bar
    Redirect permanent / https://mysite.foo.bar/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mysite.foo.bar

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/src/

        <Directory /var/www/html/src/>
            Require all granted
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?m=$1 [QSA]
            DirectoryIndex index.php
        </Directory>
        
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/foo/bar/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/foo/bar/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/foo/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

In other words, I want to redirect all traffic over port 80 to port 443, but I need to do this change automatically in my process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E '
/^\s*<VirtualHost\s.*:80>\s*$/,/^\s*<\/VirtualHost>\s*$/{
    /^\s*<\/?VirtualHost.*>\s*$/b
    /^\s*ServerName\s+(\S+).*/!d
    s%%&\n    Redirect permanent / https://\1/%
}' virtualhost.conf
```

Comment: This prints the new content correctly, but the virtualhost.conf file didn't changed. How do I replace the old content for the new one in the virtualhost.conf?

Comment: @ThiagoB.Bittencourt Add `-i` (or `--in-place`) flag to the `sed` call. Don't forget to backup the original  virtualhost.conf file, just in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { mark=1 } /^<VirtualHost \*:80>/ { print;printf "\tServerName mysite.foo.bar\n\tRedirect permanent / https://mysite.foo.bar/\n";mark=0;next } /<\/VirtualHost>/ { mark=1 }mark' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
                mark=1                                                        # Set a print marker (mark) to 1 before file processing
           } 
     /^<VirtualHost \*:80>/ {                                                  # Process when we see a Virtual Host on 80
                print;                                                         # Print the line
                printf "\tServerName mysite.foo.bar\n\tRedirect permanent / https://mysite.foo.bar/\n";                                                          # Print the additional text
                mark=0;                                                        # Set print marker to 0
                next                                                           # Skip to the next line
            } 
      /<\/VirtualHost>/ {                                                      # Process when we see a closing Virtual Host tag
                mark=1                                                         # Set print marker to 1
            }mark' file                                                        # Use print marker to distinguish what should and shouldn't print
```

Comment: Thanks, but this work only for mysite.foo.bar, I need it any site.

Comment: You would just change the text accordingly.